# How can I draw geom_line across facets or grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

My data :

```
Plate   Month   Day     Concentration
A       April   1       17.1094
B       April   2       16.001
C       April   3       17.9501
D       April   4       18.3686
E       April   5       18.3133
F       April   6       19.1189
G       May     1       16.0423
H       May     2       16.3614
I       May     3       18.5723
J       May     4       19.1091
K       May     5       17.6863
L       May     6       18.2647
```

Using geom_line I was able to draw a line graph connecting all dots in a nice plot as follows :

```
myData <- data.frame(read.table("myData.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE))

ggplot(myData, aes(x = Plate, y = Concentration, group=1)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

I differentiated data based on Month using facet panels, and then draw a line graph as follows. Here, the line plot is disconnected after the last day in April month. How can I draw line plot that draws across facets i.e. from April to May ?

```
ggplot(myData, aes(x = Day, y = Concentration)) + facet_wrap(~ Month, nrow = 1) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Facets are separate graphs. Seems like you don't want facets...

Comment: if I don't use facets, how can I represent/label Months data April vs May in my graph ?

Comment: It appears like R ggplot does not offer a solution to draw continuos line graph and differentiate/label/group data on x-axis ?

Answer (score 2):

You could fake it:

```
mydata <- "Plate   Month   Day     Concentration
A       April   1       17.1094
B       April   2       16.001
C       April   3       17.9501
D       April   4       18.3686
E       April   5       18.3133
F       April   6       19.1189
G       May     1       16.0423
H       May     2       16.3614
I       May     3       18.5723
J       May     4       19.1091
K       May     5       17.6863
L       May     6       18.2647"

myData <- data.frame(read_table(mydata))

myData <- myData %>% mutate(plot_day = seq_along(Day))
rect_data <- myData %>% group_by(Month) %>% 
  summarise(data.frame(xmin = min(plot_day), xmax=max(plot_day))) %>% 
  mutate(ymin = 19.25, ymax=19.5)

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = myData, aes(x = plot_day, y = Concentration)) + 
  geom_rect(data=rect_data, aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, xmin=xmin-c(.55, .45), xmax=xmax+c(.45, .55)), 
            fill="gray75", col="transparent") + 
  geom_text(data = rect_data, aes(x=c(3.5, 9.5), y=19.375, label = c("April", "May"))) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(.449, 12.551), ylim=c(15.75, 19.501), expand=0) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2,12, by=2), 
                     labels=c("2", "4", "6", "2", "4", "6")) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=6.5, col="white", size=2) +
  geom_line(data = myData, aes(x = plot_day, y = Concentration)) + 
  labs(x="Day")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you DaveArmstrong for this temporary solution to make the graph appear like having facets without using any grids. This works for customizing on few plots, but it becomes cumbersome to apply this customization for multiple plots recursively.